# JSON Object Exception

Tags: json, rest, web-services

I am writing a web service-REST.
I am receiving a text_plain format.

Example of my data:

```
{"data_log":
    {
       "methodClass": [{"methodName": 1, "methodStatus": "1"}, 
           {"methodName": 2, "methodStatus": "1"}]
    }
}
```

In my Restful Webservice, I try to read the data, but I got error 500 Internal Server Error-JSON Object not found.

```
public int adaptiveAuth(String objDataLog){ 
        logWriter("objDataLog:"+objDataLog);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(objDataLog);

 JSONArray methodClassObj=(JSONArray)obj.get("methodClass"); 

        if (methodClassObj != null) {
             JSONObject methodObj;
             String entrymethodName, entrymethodStatus;
             for (Object o : methodClassObj) {
                methodObj = (JSONObject) o;
                entrymethodName = String.valueOf(methodObj.get("methodName"));
                entrymethodStatus = String.valueOf(methodObj.get("methodStatus"));

                logWriter("entrymethodName:"+entrymethodName);
                logWriter("entrymethodStatus:"+entrymethodStatus);
             }

        }
}
```

I already tried to use the below code, but it still give me the error.

```
 String methodClass= obj.getJSONObject("data_log").getString("methodClass");
```

I'm expecting to put the current data into an 2 dimension array which it would be like this:

[1,1],[2,1]

Anyone could give me some suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 **Try this code for parsing json data**      

               ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
              JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

               // Getting JSON Array node
               JSONArray b= jsonObj.getJSONArray("methodClass");

               // looping through All data
               for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject c = b.getJSONObject(i);

                  String entrymethodName = c.getJSONObject("methodClass").getString("methodName");
                  String entrymethodStatus = c.getJSONObject("methodClass").getString("methodStatus");

                  // tmp hash map for storing values
                  HashMap<String, String> co = new HashMap<>();

                  // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                  co.put(entrymethodName, entrymethodStatus );


                  // adding co to  list
                  list.add(co);
```

Also check this - https://gist.github.com/codebutler/2339666

Comment: Hi,
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(objDataLog);
JSONArray b= jsonObj.getJSONArray("methodClass");

It give me error : org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["methodClass"] not found.

Comment: JSONArray methodClass= (JSONArray) obj.get("methodClass"); also returning same error

Comment: hi,
contacts in the code is an array? i didnt see any declaration

Comment: My mistakes , now try again . edited before code and this also

Comment: i still get the same error. JSON Object methodClass was not found. 
@POST
 @Path("/post")
 @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

I'm sending a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I changed by String to this format:

{   "methodSet": [
        {
            "methodName": 1,
            "methodStatus": "1"
        },
        {
            "methodName": 2,
            "methodStatus": "1"
        }
    ]
}

and for the code :

```
  ArrayList<String> listMethod = new ArrayList<String>();    
    JSONArray arr=(JSONArray)obj.get("methodClass"); 

    if (arr != null) {
        JSONObject objMethod;
        String MethodName, MethodStatus;
        for (Object o : arr) {
            objMethod = (JSONObject) o;
            MethodName = String.valueOf(objMethod.get("methodName"));
            MethodStatus = String.valueOf(objMethod.get("methodStatus"));

            int resultMethodName = Integer.parseInt(MethodName);    
            int resultMethodStatus = Integer.parseInt(MethodStatus);    

            logWriter("MethodStatus"+resultMethodName);
            logWriter("MethodName"+resultMethodStatus);

            listMethod.add("(" + MethodName + "," + MethodStatus + ")");

            logWriter("listMethod is :     "+listMethod);  


        }
    }
```